# Ubuntu in Virtual Box takes about 60 seconds to get to log in screen

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

Fresh install, current windows 10 64-bit.

Current up to date Virtual Box (6.1.6 r137129 (Qt5.6.2))

Current up to date Ubuntu (20.04)

Gave it 8GB of my 32GB ram, 128mb vRam

Gave it 3 of my 8 cores, intel i7-7700k

Enabled VT-x and 3D Acceleration

Vbox and Virtual drive both installed on an SSD, 20 GB space.  Dynamic drive.

I followed this guide in its entirety: https://www.nakivo.com/blog/install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox-virtual-machine/

Then I followed the instruction to install the expac from this guide: https://www.nakivo.com/blog/how-to-install-virtualbox-extension-pack/

Also, this attached error code comes up everytime I start ubuntu from vbox.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The message is OK. But poor performance can be fixed.

Shutdown the machine and check "Use Host I/O cache" under

Storage -> Controller: SATA settings

This question is really unrelated to Ubuntu. This is a wrong VB default setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's a bug (or, maybe, feature) in Virtualbox 6.1 version. You could, try installing Virtualbox 6.0 version and check if your ubuntu VM boots faster.

Enabling **Use Host I/O cache** didn't help in my case also. But, as Pilot6 said, it's probably not Ubuntu's issue, but Virtualbox's.

Comment: In my case it helped a lot, but I ran it on Ubuntu host. Without that enabled it was veeery slow.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ok. Maybe different hardware combinations address different virtualbox issues)